# Magento 1.9.2.4 login error not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9

My website - http://sdl2.alphalogichq.com/index.php/customer/account/login/ login works ok.

But if there is any invalid login like:

email: abc@abc.com
password: 123456

It doesn't show Invalid login error. I have to force reload (CTRL + F5) so it shows the error.

Why is it not working correctly?

Comment: for me it showing `invalid login error` once i clicked on "login" button....

Comment: @BabyinMagento - I just tried again. It doesn't show me the first time but it works if I force reload. It looks like it is getting cached.

Comment: seems like arjun's solution will work.... try in other browsers private window.....

Comment: also it showing `Invalid login or password.` 5 times once i visited link....

Comment: @BabyinMagento - yes, there is something wrong. Can you tell what?

Comment: did you recently done any chnages, is it working before, did you installed any modules, also please check var folder for logs.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [image]

I think you should clear you browser cache

Comment: can you try again? I think this doesn't happen with first time users.

Comment: I tried once again it still gives above error of my ans.